# Mathematical expression in tick mark labels, ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I want to make  tick mark labels using mathematical expressions. 
See the next example:

```
library(tidyverse)    
gl<-30
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(-5, 5)), aes(x)) +
      stat_function(fun = dt, args = list(df = 30))+ylab("f(t)")+
      geom_segment(aes(x=qt(.975,gl),xend=qt(.975,gl),y=0,yend=dt(qt(.975,gl),gl)))+
      scale_x_continuous("t", round(c(-5,qt(1-.975,gl),0,qt(.975,gl),5),3), limits=c(-5,5),labels=c("-5.000", "-2.042",  "0"  ,"list(q[0.95]==0.025)",  "5.000"))+
      annotate("segment", x = c(2.2), xend = c(3.8), 
               y = c(0.02), yend = c(.16), colour = "red", size=1, alpha=0.6, arrow=arrow())+
      annotate("segment", x = c(-1), xend = c(-3), 
               y = c(0.02), yend = c(.16), colour = 1, size=1, alpha=0.6, arrow=arrow())+
      stat_function(fun = dt, args = list(df = gl),
                    xlim = c(-5,qt(.975,gl)),
                    geom = "area",fill="red",alpha=0.5)+
        annotate("text", x = c(-3.8,3.8,4), y = c(0.18,0.18,.3), 
               label = c("1-alpha","alpha/2","list(q[0.95]==0.025)"),parse=T , size=4 , fontface="bold")+
      theme_bw()
```

[image]
If line

```
scale_x_continuous("t", round(c(-5,qt(1-.975,gl),0,qt(.975,gl),5),3), limits=c(-5,5),labels=c("-5.000", "-2.042",  "0"  ,"list(q[0.95]==0.025)",  "5.000"))
```

Is replaced by

```
scale_x_continuous("t", round(c(-5,qt(1-.975,gl),0,qt(.975,gl),5),3), limits=c(-5,5),labels=c("-5.000", "-2.042",  "0"  ,"list(q[0.95]==0.025)",  "5.000"),parse=T)
```

An error is obtained:

> Error in scale_x_continuous("t", round(c(-5, qt(1 - 0.975, gl), 0,
>   qt(0.975,  :   unused argument (parse = T)

How to achieve mathematical expressions in scale_x_continuous as is achieved in annotate?

Comment: "An error is obtained." Would you mind editing your post to include the error message?

Comment: @duckmayr Done. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [plotmath](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html) expressions in expression vectors to make this happen.

```r
library(tidyverse)
mf<-55
sdf<-8
weight_lim<-c(30, 110)
xlabels <- expression(
  "-5.000",
  "-2.042",
  "0",
  q[0.95]==0.025,
  "5.000"
)
ggplot(data = data.frame(weight = weight_lim), aes(weight)) +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, n = 101, args = list(mean = mf, sd = sdf),color=2) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=50,xend=50,y=c(0),yend=c(dnorm(50,mf,sdf))),linetype=2,col=2)+
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mf,sd=sdf),
                xlim = c(weight_lim[1],50),
                geom = "area",fill="red",alpha=0.5)+
  ylab("f(weight)") + scale_x_continuous("t", seq(weight_lim[1],weight_lim[2], length.out =5), 
                                         limits=weight_lim, 
                                         labels= xlabels) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
xlabels <- c(
  ~ "-5.000",
  ~ "-2.042",
  ~ "0",
  ~ list(q[0.95]==0.025),
  ~ "5.000"
)
ggplot(......) + ...... + 
  scale_x_continuous("t", round(c(-5,qt(1-.975,gl),0,qt(.975,gl),5),3), 
                     limits=c(-5,5), 
                     labels= xlabels)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to automate the creation of `xlabels`? If I have a vector of labels `lbls`, how to ensemble `xlabels` as for example `paste(“~”,lbls)` ? (this clearly doesn't work)

Comment: in R version 4.0.2 this gets an error: Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  invalid mathematical annotation

Comment: The problem is not R 4.0 but rather more recent versions of ggplot2. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62923231/4975218